# what the difference between ros/groovy/share and ros/groovy/stacks?

Tags: ros, stacks, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,there:
i found that all packages in ros/groovy/share contains a "cmake" directory which has several .cmake files. while packages in ros/groovy/stacks did not. So i am wondering what  is the difference between share and stacks. put differently, how can we decide which directroy(share or stacks) to put a package in?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98626/what-the-difference-between-ros/groovy/share-and-ros/groovy/stacks?/) by [zhongjin616](https://answers.ros.org/users/8531/zhongjin616/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ros groovy is the first release that can use both catkin and rosbuild. If i'm not wrong, in the stacks folder there are the packages that are under rosbuild, while in the share folder the packages that use catkin. In ros hydro the stacks folder has been removed and there is only /ros/hydro/share. Anyway, answering your second question, when you create a package, you should put it in a workspace in your home directory and never in the /ros/groovy/... directory!

---

Originally posted by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) with karma: 808 on 2013-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zhongjin616](https://answers.ros.org/users/8531/zhongjin616/) on 2013-11-07**:
thanks for your answer with enthusiasm. by the way,can you explain what is the function of the .cmake file in "cmake" directory? and in what kind of situation will i need to use it?